# How can I pass a select HTML element as a parameter in a onSubmit form call?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to pass the html elements of a form through the submit function as parameters. I can get correctly the nameInput element with flag #nameInput, but the select element (#skillSelect) is throwing this error:

```
- error TS2339: Property 'skillSelect' does not exist on type 'MemberFilterComponent'.
```

Here is my form template. How can I pass the select element to component as I did with the input text?:

```
<form
  [formGroup]="filterMemberForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(nameInput, skillSelect)"
>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="font-weight-bold"
        >Name
        <input
          ngDefaultControl
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          label="'Name'"
          formControlName="name"
          placeholder=" Ex: Maria Novillo"
          required
          id="name"
          #nameInput
          (change)="mapChipValue(nameInput)"
      /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" *ngIf="skills.length !== 0">
      <label class="font-weight-bold">Skills:</label>
      <select
        id="skillId"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="skillId"
        #skillSelect
        (change)="mapChipValue(skillSelect)"
      >
        <option value="">-- Select skills --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill.idSkill">
          {{ skill.skill }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Apply</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you need pass the "html element"? in `filterMemberForm.value` you has an object with the values. Really your form should be

```
<form
  [formGroup]="filterMemberForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(filterMemberForm)"
>

onSubmit(form:FromGroup)
{
   if (form.valid)
      console.log(form.value)
   else
      form.markAllAsTouched()
}
```

if you need the selectOption name always can makes

```
onSubmit(form:FromGroup)
{
   if (form.valid)
   {
      //if is not multiple select
      const selectedItem=this.skills.find(x=>x.idSkill==form.value.skillId)
      console.log(form.value,selectedItem)

      //if is multiple select
      const selectedItems=this.skills.filter(
             x=>form.value.skillId.indexOf(x.idSkill)>=0)

      console.log(form.value,selectedItems)
   }
   else
      form.markAllAsTouched()
}
```

Comment: I need it because for input text I want values and for select element I need the selected option text, not the value.

Comment: @doubting, you can get it using the array "this.skills", see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In the html file:

```
<select class='select-option'
#mySelect
(change)='onOptionsSelected(mySelect.value)'>
 <option class='option' 
*ngFor='let option of dropDownData' 
[value]="option.seo_val">{{option.text_val}}</option>
</select>
```

In the ts file:

```
onOptionsSelected(value:string){
 console.log("the selected value is " + value);
}
```

Comment: I misunderstood your question at the beginning, but I updated my answer now, please have a look on it.